# Why does the n variable need to be directly in the while-loop

Tags: r

How come it is that in the while-loop in the bottom I need to put in the whole of the s-variable instead of just typing in s i. e. why does the n-variable need to be shown in the loop

```
rm(list=ls())

nm <- c(585,578,568)
nf <- c(632,510,589)
ym <- c(543,522,510)
yf <- c(560,466,536)
y.barm <- ym/nm  
y.barf <- yf/nf

#a)
s <- sqrt(y.barm[2]*(1-y.barm[2])/nm[2] + y.barm[3]*(1-y.barm[3])/nm[3])
y.barm[2]-y.barm[3]+qnorm(0.005)*s
y.barm[2]-y.barm[3]-qnorm(0.005)*s
#Så konfindensintervallet er givet ved (-0.04,0.05)

#b)
s2 <- sqrt(y.barm[2]*(1-y.barm[2])/nm[2] + y.barf[2]*(1-y.barf[2])/nm[2])
y.barm[2]-y.barf[2]+qnorm(0.005)*s2
y.barm[2]-y.barf[2]-qnorm(0.005)*s2
#Så konfindensintervallet er (-0.054,0.033)

#Opg. 8.107
p2 <- ym[2]/nm[2]
p3 <- ym[3]/nm[2]
n <- 522
s <- sqrt((p2*(1-p2) + p3*(1-p3))/n)
x <- -qnorm(0.025)*s #(0.015 på hver side. Derfor skal der ikke ganges med 2)

while(x > 0.031){
n <- n + 1
x <- -qnorm(0.025)*sqrt((p2*(1-p2) + p3*(1-p3))/n) #DOESN'T WORK WHEN I TYPE IN THE s VARIABLE. I NEED TO WRITE OUT THE WHOLE THING. HOW COME??
}

n
```

Comment: it worked for me `while(x > 0.031){
  n <- n + 1
  x <- -qnorm(0.025)*s 
}`

Comment: This shouldn't be happening, as variables declared before and outside the loop [should be available to use inside the loop](http://rextester.com/ZLGXZ47343).  Please give us a reproduible example.

Comment: he already gave an example

Comment: I think what is meant by "doesn't work" is that it produces the wrong result. `s` is not updating every time `n` is updated, since it was previously defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s` is a fixed value that retains the value it was assigned before you began altering `n` in the `while` loop.  To get a dynamic value, you should use a function to get the standard error and use that in your loop, such as this combination

```
s_fun <- function(p1, p2, p3, n){
  sqrt((p2*(1-p2) + p3*(1-p3))/n)
}


while(x > 0.031){
  n <- n + 1
  x <- -qnorm(0.025) * s_fun(p1, p2, p3, n) 
}
```